# Bulk Insert failed when executed from remote client but success on local

Tags: sql-server, ssms, bulkinsert, impersonation

Please find the diagram as below for my issue:

[image]

I have 3 servers in the same domain, there is a SQL Server instance A (it's windows service run under domain\User1), In this instance, we have a Stored Procedure used for BULK INSERT a text file from a network shared folder in server C, the domain\User1 has full permissions on this folder.

My issue is: The Stored Procedure runs ok (green arrow) when connecting by SSMS in its (server A). But it failed when I change to SSMS in server B (log in by the same domain\User1 to the same Instance A). The error is "Access denied" to the text file (red arrow). Does the client have a role in this? I think the client does not matter, the file reading is done from the server (by the user that run Instance A service)

Note: If I connect Instance A from SSMS B with SQL Logon User (not windows account), the stored procedure works fine.

Could anyone give me some advice and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Hi! You need add user1 on share folder under domain. Access denied just for network security. And in this solution you just add user, user1. I tried it.

Comment: @Amirhossein: I have granted read/write on share folder for domain\User1 already. But it only works if I call from SSMS A. I have tried login Server B by domain\User1 and access to that shared folder ok. Btw, granting Everyone for this folder still not work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a link answer but hopefully it helps.

BTW I commend you for taking the time to analyse the issue to the extent of drawing a diagram. This is far higher quality than most questions on here.

I believe you are running into a double hop issue. I searched everywhere for the BULK INSERT permission model and finally found this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189676/why-is-bulk-insert-considered-dangerous

which says this about using BULK INSERT:

> When accessing SQL Server via a Windows Login, that Windows account
> will be impersonated (even if you switch the security context using
> EXECUTE AS LOGIN='...') for doing the file system access

and this

> when accessing SQL Server via a SQL Server Login, then the external
> access is done in the context of the SQL Server service account

When you have issues with windows authentication and there is three servers and impersonation, it's often a double hop issue.

This may help you with that:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44524/bulk-insert-through-network

Which in turn references this:

https://thesqldude.com/2011/12/30/how-to-sql-server-bulk-insert-with-constrained-delegation-access-is-denied/